# Sharing RSO2 Topic communication between containers operating on two Windows host machines A and B, each equipped with Docker

Tags: docker, ros2

I'd like to provide a clear explanation of my scenario, which should be easy to reproduce.

I've been attempting to facilitate ROS2 topic communication between containers. One container resides on Machine A, while another is on Machine B. Both machines are Windows hosts connected via the same local network.

Requirements:
[Can check the image for understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xbNVL.png)
Two Windows host machines, version 10 or above.
Docker installed on both machines.
Cyclone DDS.
ROS2 Humble docker image image.
Thank you.

When I publish data from Machine A, I'm not receiving any response on the subscriber container located on Machine B. I've tried running both Docker images with the --net=host option, one on Machine A and the other on Machine B. Additionally, setting up the ROS_DOMAIN_ID in the environment hasn't resolved the issue.

Additionally i can ping from publisher container to subscriber container.

I would greatly appreciate it if I could receive a working solution for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.